# how to convert left join SQL script to Linq script?

Tags: sql, linq

How can I convert `left join` to linq script. I have a T-SQL like this:

```
SELECT
    es.StandardID,
    COUNT(DISTINCT esc.StandardCourseID) AS CourseIDCount,
    COUNT(DISTINCT esp.StandardPostID) AS PostIDCount
FROM EduStandards AS es
LEFT JOIN EduStandardCourses AS esc
    ON es.StandardID = esc.StandardID
LEFT JOIN EduStandardPosts AS esp
    ON es.StandardID = esp.StandardID
GROUP BY es.StandardID
```

That I want to convert this to linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the query with left join that is replica of your query in linq.

```
var query = (from es in dbContext.EduStandards
                    join esc in dbContext.EduStandardCourses on es.StandardID equals esc.StandardID into ssc
                    from esc in ssc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join esp in dbContext.EduStandardPosts on es.StandardID equals esp.StandardID into ssp
                    from esp in ssp.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { StandardId = es.StandardID, CourseCount = ssc.Count(), PostCount = ssp.Count() }).Distinct().ToList();
```

But I think we need not to apply left join in linq to calculate count. Following optimized linq query will return same result.

```
var query2 = (from es in dbContext.EduStandards
                     join esc in dbContext.EduStandardCourses on es.StandardID equals esc.StandardID into ssc
                     join esp in dbContext.EduStandardPosts on es.StandardID equals esp.StandardID into ssp
                     select new { StandardId = es.StandardID, CourseCount = ssc.Count(), PostCount = ssp.Count() });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've come up with

```
var query = from es in db.EduStandards
            join esc1 in db.EduStandardCourses 
            on es.StandardId equals esc1.StandardId into esc
            from c in esc.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join esp1 in db.EduStandardPosts 
            on es.StandardId equals esp1.StandardId into esp
            from p in esp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { es.StandardId, Course = c, Post = p } by es.StandardId into g
            select new
            {
                StandardId = g.Key,
                CourseIdCount = g.Where(x => x.Course != null).Count(),
                PostIdCount = g.Where(x => x.Post != null).Count(),
            };
```

However, I'm not entirely sure if it'll work for EF.

You could always do something like this:

```
var query =  from es in db.EduStandards
             select new
             {
                 es.StandardId,
                 CourseIdCount = db.EduStandardCourses.Where(esc => esc.StandardId == es.StandardId).Distinct().Count(),
                 PostIdCount = db.EduStandardPosts.Where(esp => esp.StandardId == es.StandardId).Distinct().Count()
             };
```

Also, I can't attest to the performance of either one of these queries due to the lack of knowledge of your database.